# File Transfer Between Paired Bluetooth Devices (Win8 + mobile)

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, file-transfer

I'm looking for native methods to transfer files between my Win 8 box and my Android phone. Both have bluetooth capabilities and I can easily pair the devices...but this seems utterly useless since no visible options exist to do anything with this connection.

Pro tips?

Also, other ways I can use the bluetooth connection between my Win 8 box and my Android might prove highly interesting.

Comment: try Droid Explorer: http://de.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Are you dead set on using bluetooth? Bluetooth is painfully slow for file transfers.

If you want to transfer from the phone to the computer you can just use the built-in `share` menu and choose bluetooth. From the computer to the phone, select a file and use `right-click` and choose `Send to -> Bluetooth`

Are both devices on the same network/LAN? [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) works great if you connect your Android device to your network via Wifi.